# If $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}g(x) = L \gt 0$, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)g(x) = \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

I think this proof is straightforward...just wanted to make sure I did not overlook anything:

**Prove the following statement**:

> If $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}g(x) = L \gt 0$, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)g(x) = \infty$

---

*Relevant Definitions*

(1) $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty \iff \forall M \gt 0 \ \exists N \in \mathbb R \text{ s.t. } \forall x \in \mathbb R \Big [ x \gt N \rightarrow f(x) \gt M \Big ]$

(2) $\lim_{x\to \infty}g(x) = L \iff \forall \epsilon \gt 0 \ \exists P \in \mathbb R \text{ s.t. } \forall x \in \mathbb R \Big [ x \gt P \rightarrow |g(x) - L | \lt \epsilon \Big ]$

(3) $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)g(x) = \infty \iff \forall A \gt 0 \ \exists Q \in \mathbb R \text{ s.t. } \forall x \in \mathbb R \Big [ x \gt Q \rightarrow f(x)g(x) \gt A \Big ]$

---

Consider an arbitrary $A \gt 0$. By definition (1), consider when $M:=\frac{2A}{L}$. Then we know that there is an $N_{\frac{2A}{L}}$ such that:

$$\forall x \in \mathbb R \Big [ x \gt N_{\frac{2A}{L}} \rightarrow f(x) \gt \frac{2A}{L} \Big ] \quad \quad (*)$$

Next, by defintion (2), consider when $\epsilon: = \frac{L}{2}$. Then we know that there is a $P_{\frac{L}{2}}$ such that:

$$\forall x \in \mathbb R \Big [ x \gt P_{\frac{L}{2}} \rightarrow |g(x) - L | \lt \frac{L}{2} \Big ]$$

Importantly, because of our choice in $\epsilon$, we ensure that if $x \gt  P_{\frac{L}{2}}$, then the $g(x)$ we are dealing with is positive:

$$|g(x) - L | \lt \frac{L}{2} \iff -\frac{L}{2} \lt g(x) - L \lt \frac{L}{2}$$

Adding $L$ to the inequality and recalling that $L \gt 0$, we have:

$$0\lt\frac{L}{2} \lt g(x) \lt \frac{3L}{2} \quad \quad (\dagger)$$

In addition to $x \gt P_{\frac{L}{2}}$, if we also stipulate that $x \gt N_{\frac{2A}{L}}$, then we know that $f(x)$ is positive because $A \gt 0$ and $L \gt 0 \implies \frac{2A}{L} \gt 0$ and by $(*)$, $f(x) \gt \frac{2A}{L}$. Therefore, if we multiply $(\dagger)$ by $f(x)$, we have:

$$0\lt f(x) \frac{L}{2} \lt f(x)g(x) \lt f(x)\frac{3L}{2}$$

But $0 \lt \frac{2A}{L} \lt f(x) \implies 0 \lt \frac{2A}{L} * \frac{L}{2} = A \lt f(x) * \frac{L}{2}$

We thus arrive at:

$$0 \lt A \lt f(x)g(x)$$

Referring to definition (3), we construct a $Q_A = \max(N_{\frac{2A}{L}},P_{\frac{L}{2}})$ to ensure that our $x$'s satisfy our desired conditions.

Comment: As a useful corollary, we can see that the same result is true as we approach $-\infty$; simply modify $x \gt N_{\frac{2A}{L}}$ to $x \lt N_{\frac{2A}{L}}$ and $x \gt P_{\frac{L}{2}}$ to $x \lt P_{\frac{L}{2}}$. Then, change the final line to $Q_A = \min(N_{\frac{2A}{L}},P_{\frac{L}{2}})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct and thorough.

One downright pedantic comment: when you introduce $A$, you may want to mention that $A$ is an arbitrary *positive* number, not just any number.